# Moments of an exponential random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> If $X$ is an exponential random variable with mean $\frac{1}{γ}$, show that $\\E[X^k]=\frac{k!}{γ^k},\,\,$ for $\, \, \, k=1,2,3$...

How would I go about proving this?

Comment: Induction? ${}{}{}$

Comment: Can you prove it for $k=1$?  How about $k=2$?  What approach do you use for $k=2$?  Generalize.

Answer (score 4):

The induction step uses integration by parts.
$$E[X^{k+1}] = \int_0^\infty x^{k+1} \gamma e^{-\gamma x} \mathop{dx}
= (k+1)\int x^k e^{-\gamma x} \mathop{dx} = \frac{k+1}{\gamma} E[X^k].$$

Answer (score 2):

[Moment generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function) of the exponential RV is $$\frac{1}{1-t\gamma^{-1}},\,t<\gamma$$ So $$M_X(t)=\mathsf{E}\{e^{tX}\}=1+t\mathsf{E}\{X\}+\frac{t^2\mathsf{E}\{X^2\}}{2!}+\frac{t^3\mathsf{E}\{X^3\}}{3!}+\cdots=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} t^k\frac{\mathsf{E}\{X^k\}}{k!}=\frac{1}{1-t\gamma^{-1}}$$
Expanding the RHS using 
$\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n,\,|x|<1$ for $x=t\gamma^{-1}$
$$\frac{1}{1-t\gamma^{-1}}=1+t\gamma^{-1}+(t\gamma^{-1})^2+\cdots=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} t^k(\gamma^{-k})$$

and the coefficients of $t^k$ should be identical.  That is

$$\gamma^{-k}=\frac{\mathsf{E}\{X^k\}}{k!}\Rightarrow \mathsf{E}\{X^k\}=\gamma^{-k}k!$$

Comment: So circular.  You do realise that Ryan Smith is likely being asked to find $\mathsf E(X^k)$ as a lead into *deriving* the moment generating function, right?  (Although this is still useful as a guide to reverse engineering a method to do so.)

Comment: Yes @GrahamKemp, that is also a possibility. But in that case the MGF can be derived more easily by directly calculating $\mathsf{E}(e^{tX})$. I think the main idea is to understand the term-by-term relation of the Taylor expansion of MGF and the moments of the RV, which is highlighted here.